# Javascript - Find a specfic property in object by value which is a list of strings

Tags: javascript

I have to find a property in array of objects by value which is a list of strings.

For example I have someting like this:

```
const colors ={
colors-1: [{color: 'blue'}], 
colors-2: [{color: 'gray'}, {color: 'red'}], 
colors-3: [{color: 'white'}]
}
```

And I want to get for example property `colors-2` by string which is inside array value.

Something like this:

```
findPropertyByValue(colors, 'red')
```

And output:

```
'colors-2'
```

Could You show me how to achieve this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `find` and `some`.
It takes the entries of the `colors` object and finds the entry which has an element with the input color.
The find returns an entry with `[key,value]` so to get key take the 0th element

Here I assumed that a single color has a unique key.
added the `?.` before `[0]` (optional chaining - access only if available) so that when a color that is not found is input there will be no errors (returns `undefined`). `||` operator used to return a message like "not found" if the find step returns `undefined`

```js
const colors ={
'colors-1': [{color: 'blue'}], 
'colors-2': [{color: 'gray'}, {color: 'red'}], 
'colors-3': [{color: 'white'}]
}

const findPropertyByValue = (obj,col) => Object.entries(obj).find(([k,v])=>v.some(({color}) => color===col))?.[0] || 'not found'


console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors,'white'))
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors,'gray'))
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors,'red'))
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors,'blue'))
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors,'green'))
```

Comment: What happens on: `console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors,'cyan'))` --> it throws an error, I think. This is the same approach I had taken earlier. May need to consider not-found case.

Comment: @jsN00b yep one line answer is not possible then :(

Comment: It is. Seems like you're a fan of the implicit return as well. Using object.keys it can be done. :) Or, optional-chaining as well.

Comment: @jsN00b actually one lined it  :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could achieve what you want. Notice I added your object keys in quotes, because they contain `-`, it wouldn't work other way.

```js
const colors = {
  "colors-1": [{ color: "blue" }],
  "colors-2": [{ color: "gray" }, { color: "red" }],
  "colors-3": [{ color: "white" }]
};

function findPropertyByValue(colors, value) {
  for (let color in colors) {
    if (colors[color].some((c) => c.color == value)) {
      return color;
    }
  }
  return ""; // if there isn't one
}
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors, "red"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
const colors = {
  "colors-1": [{ color: "blue" }],
  "colors-2": [{ color: "gray" }, { color: "red" }],
  "colors-3": [{ color: "white" }],
};

function findPropertyByValue(obj, colorName) {
  return Object.entries(obj).find((entry) =>
    entry[1].some((color) => color.color === colorName)
  )?.[0];
}

console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors, "red"));
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors, "not in list"));
```

And this solution will return all fields with specified color:

```
const colors = {
  "colors-1": [{ color: "blue" }],
  "colors-2": [{ color: "gray" }, { color: "red" }],
  "colors-3": [{ color: "white" }],
  "colors-4": [{ color: "white" }, { color: "red" }],
};

function findPropertyByValue(obj, colorName) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (acc, entry) =>
      entry[1].some((color) => color.color === colorName)
        ? [...acc, entry[0]]
        : acc,
    []
  );
}

console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors, "red"));
console.log(findPropertyByValue(colors, "not in list"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const findPropertyByValue = (haystack, needle) => (
  Object.keys(haystack)
  .find(
    k => (haystack[k]).some(
      ({color}) => color === needle
    )
  ) || 'not found'
);

const colors ={
"colors-1": [{color: 'blue'}], 
"colors-2": [{color: 'gray'}, {color: 'red'}], 
"colors-3": [{color: 'white'}]
};

console.log('find red: ', findPropertyByValue(colors, 'red'));
console.log('find cyan: ', findPropertyByValue(colors, 'cyan'));
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over the object's (`haystack`) keys
- `.find` in the value array an element whose `color` prop matches `needle` (the color being searched)
- If any such a match is found, then return the key
- Else, return `not found`